# Tapestry5 display grid component using a hashmap

Tags: java, tapestry

I am trying to attempt to display a hashmap using a grid component. If I use

```
List list = CollectionFactory.newList(MyHashMap);
```

it returns a list however on my template page I see `<theader>Empty</tHeader>` and `<tbody>false</tbody>` when passing my parameter `t:souce="list"`  to my grid component, therefore my grid component only returns one row.

Some code snippets would be a great help.

Many thanks

Comment: for sure, this is a typo: it should be 't:source="list"'

Answer (score 1):

besides the typo (see my comment) try to give the hashmap values as input to the newList method:

```
CollectionFactory.newList(MyHashMap.values());
```